# USB RootFS Problems

Tags: boot, sd-card, storage

I've got another puzzle for you.
I've recently switched my Pi so that it boots on the SD card, and runs root on a USB Disk.
Problem is, when I switched the cmdline.txt to search for the USB drive instead of booting to the normal drive, I input some information that it gave me, and although I found it unusual, I input it there anyways because it was seemingly correct (on the RPi anyways), and now that I've done the reboot, it doesn't work because the USB is located somewhere else then my SD card is told it is.
I cannot remove my SD card from the Pi because as I stated in my previous post, the connector is broken and I did some DIY'ing to get it to work, so removing the SD card and changing the info on my computer is not an option.

Is there any way that I can boot the SD card in a maintenance mode of sorts so that it also roots from the SD card, to give a commandline(terminal) to allow me to change the number again?

The quicker the answer is sent to me, the more I'd appreciate it.
Thanks,
Safixk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `safe mode` jumper trick. It's explained in my [answer here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/easiest-way-to-return-to-a-known-good-state-when-overclocking/1854#1854). It should ignore the content of `config.txt` file and use default values, booting to minimalistic busybox based system from `kernel_emergency.img` (providing that you have one).