# Key Combination to interrupt bootup and get a terminal?

Tags: raspbian, boot, display, boot-issues

Is there a way for me to interrupt the boot of the raspberry pi and go into the terminal straightaway?

**Background:**
I have installed a faulty LCD display driver, so I am connected to my HDMI display & my LCD screen. In the very beginning the pi show up on the HDMI screen, but then switches to the LCD screen - which does not work. I would like to access the terminal very early on, ideally, and then change it back to HDMI, but not sure if there is a key combination for this or something?

Comment: Why not just login via SSH and make the changes then reboot?

Comment: good idea! but won't i need to know the pi's ip address?

Comment: or hostname you can try raspberrypi.local. You may also be able to check the IP in your router.

Comment: ok that worked! thanks! but just out of curiosity: is there a way to start the terminal at bootup with a hotkey?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, but you can switch to a virtual terminal once the machine is up with the keyboard combo Ctrl + Alt + F1 through F7. You can also change the Pi to boot to a terminal from raspi-config, then start the GUI with startx.

Comment: IIRC You can also boot to recovery mode by holding down the shift key while booting

Comment: Here are a few more methods to recover your system https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/easiest-way-to-return-to-a-known-good-state-when-overclocking