# `arm_freq` in config.txt on Raspberry Pi 3 model B

Tags: pi-3, retropie, config.txt

I would like to know if it is safe to edit the config.txt file on a Retropie image to change the `arm_freq=800` to `arm_freq=1200` since it will be running on a R-pi 3 model B?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi Model B 3 Overclocking?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43303/raspberry-pi-model-b-3-overclocking)

Comment: The Pi 3 starts at 1200 MHz (1.2 GHz) so there would be no reason to make this change.

Comment: The reason I would make the change is because in the config.txt file it says it's set to 700 MHz by default

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1219/how-do-i-determine-the-current-mhz Also note that the file says `700` but when used on the RPi Zero, it still runs at 1 Ghz.

Comment: The Pi 3 runs at 1.2GHz by default, it cannot be overclocked, but I imagine it could be under-clocked. Although I would not recommend this if you are using RetroPie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi 3 Model B starts at 1.2Ghz regardless of what `/boot/config.txt` says. Here are the results of my clock speed files on my Pi 3 with `config.txt` not edited from a fresh card:

```
sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
1200000
```

When not under load:

```
sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
600000
```

When playing music with `mpg321`:

```
sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
1200000
```

You do not need to change `/boot/config.txt` if you want your Pi 3 running at 1.2Ghz, if you want to overclock it, that is a whole different question. Hope this helps.